# Springboot WebSecurityConfig ignore filter

Tags: angular, rest, authentication, jwt, websecurity

My problem is that when I log in, spring boot security already asks for a bearer token while it is not yet present. Therefore, the filter should not be executed with a specific request which in my case is /authenticate

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    // We don't need CSRF for this example
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            // dont authenticate this particular request
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/authenticate", "/register").permitAll().
            // all other requests need to be authenticated
                    anyRequest().authenticated().and().
            // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
            // store user's state.
                    exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

But with this method the filters are always executed on any request also the /authenticate which is not the intention.

Comment: Hm, I just added your code to my project which works in almost the same way and it works. I can login an all other requests are secured.
I see just one difference: httpSecurity.cors(); before adding the filter, but I am not sure if that makes the difference ..

Comment: @SimonEchle Thank you for your comment, I will try it out